# How to create a setup of android project which work on android mobile?

Tags: android, installation

I have created a demo android application.I want to create a setup of demo android project which should install on all android device directly without android market to check application working or not just like a window application.

Thank's in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you should export you android project to apk.....by going to **Android Tools-> Export Signed Application Package -> then follow on screen instruction**

Then you should connect your devices to computer and run the following command from terminal:

```
adb install "path to apk file"
```

Comment: how can i "Enter path to keystore". After export application package

Comment: how can i create it as i just created a folder but it not picking up.

Comment: ok!! now i have two file in my folder one is .apk and other is .keystore .how i run directly on my phone

Comment: there are two ways to run it on your phone.......1: copy this .apk file to your fone sdcad and install it using astro manager file......2: use command adb install "path to apk file" from your terminal

Comment: Yeah!! it work's Great.can you help me on previous question.Sure i will vote don't worry.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test your application on all devices you only need to copy .apk file present in your bin folder. It is by default signed with your default keystore. If you did not find any .apk file inside your bin folder than you have to clean build your project once and run it once. Framework will generate one .apk file automatically.

Now only you need to deploy your apk to all devices where you want to test or you can run adb command if your device is in debug mode.

adb install "apk path"

Comment: Good answer but i wanted full step.stay in touch.